# Why can’t Swift’s string constructor be used to convert a generic to a string?

Tags: swift, generics

Consider the following example.

```
func printGeneric<T>(_ input: T) {
    let output = String(input)
    print(output)
}
```

This will result in the error `cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(T)'`. *(tested in playground)*

However, for some reason, this does work.

```
func printGeneric<T>(_ input: T) {
    let output = "\(input)"
    print(output)
}
```

Why does the first method not work, but the second does? What is the 'proper' way to get the string representation of a generic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
func printGeneric<T>(_ input: T) {
    let output = String(describing:input)
    print(output)
}
```

As for why:

- The first way, `String(x)`, is for specific situations where `x` is of a type that can be coerced to String, for use within your program. In other words, it is a type where each value has a string *equivalent*, like `1` and `"1"`. (See on [LosslessStringConvertible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/losslessstringconvertible).) We don't know whether T is that sort of type, so the compilation fails.
- But `String(describing:x)` is exactly the same as `"\(x)"` — it is intended for printing *anything* to the console. It is not a coercion but a string representation.

You could also choose to use `String(reflecting:)`; it is subtly different from `String(describing:)`.

Comment: If it was important to you to be able to say `String(T)` for a bunch of types you are defining, you could declare a protocol, define a String initializer for that protocol type, and constrain T with that protocol type.